# webpack 2 cannot find module

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-2

I got this error with one of my js

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '[object Object]' in 'C:\Users\My-Laptop\Projects\myapp @ ./resources/assets/app/entries/landing.js 6:0-45
```

I don't think there's a problem with my entry's config. It's like this

```
entry : { landing: ' ./resources/assets/app/entries/landing.js' }
```

My landing.js is here http://pastebin.com/TkEJ3570

Need help and thanks!

Comment: It looks like it's an error with your import, not your entry point.

Comment: @MinusFour I don't get any error when I use webpack 1. Are you saying my error is in landing.js? then why there isn't any error when I compile with webpack 1?

Comment: You'll have to provide more information. The failing code in landing.js and your webpack config. Have you followed the upgrade steps to move to webpack 2?

Comment: @jontem yes of course.

Comment: So the row thats failing is the import of the less file? Please share your webpack config